# How to merge the items of list if they are same and append if items are not same in Python

Tags: python, list, append

I have a list `tags` which contains below `dict` data

```
tags = [ {'Time': 1, 'Name': 'John'} ]
```

I am getting `tags` value from a function. Some time the values received has same `Name` so in this case I need to simply get its `Time` value and update the list. For ex if below data is received:

```
tags = [ {'Time': 4, 'Name': 'John'} ]
```

In this case, as `Name` is same so I will simply get the `Time` value and update the `tags` list so output will be:

```
output = [ {'Time': 4, 'Name': 'John'} ]
```

Time has changed from 1 to 4. But lets say a new `Name` is received, for ex below:

```
tags = [ {'Time': 10, 'Name': 'John'}, {'Time': 6, 'Name': 'Karan'} ]
```

So in this case `John` time will be updated and `Karan` time data will be appended to list so output will be

```
output = [ {'Time': 10, 'Name': 'John'}, {'Time': 6, 'Name': 'Karan'} ]
```

So for John we have updated the time and Karan data has been added.

I have `output_tags` as `dict` which has a `tags` as `list` in it. I am doing the below:

```
output_tags['Tags'].clear()
for tag in tags:
    output_tags['Tags'].append(tag)
```

Now above code is clearing whatever data we had in `output_tags['Tags']` and then simply append all the data. So this way we will update the same `Name` time and also append any new `Name` received.

But using this code, I was clearing any previous data I had. For ex, sometime back I received `Ellis` data but now I am not receiving `Ellis` data. I still need to keep `Ellis` data but it was getting cleared. Is there any other way I can resolve this issue. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you convert that list to a dictionary `{"John": 1}`? Then updates are trivial, and you can easily output the list of dicts again with e.g. `[{"Time": value, "Name": key} for key, value in tag_dict.items()]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge your two lists of tags :

```py
from collections import defaultdict

tags = [ {'Time': 10, 'Name': 'John'}, {'Time': 6, 'Name': 'Karan'} ]
new_tags = [ {'Time': 30, 'Name': 'Bob'}, {'Time': 40, 'Name': 'Karan'} ]

d = defaultdict(dict)
# using defaultdict(dict), whatever the key your using, it will be initiated with a dict : `d['random_key'] == {}` is True

# we fill d with all tags and new_tags using `Name` as key
for list_ in (tags, new_tags):
    for obj in list_:
        # if `obj['Name']` has already been set, it is updated
        # otherwise it is added
        d[obj['Name']].update(obj)

# display only values and make it a list
results = list(d.values())

print(results)

# [{'Time': 10, 'Name': 'John'}, {'Time': 40, 'Name': 'Karan'}, {'Time': 30, 'Name': 'Bob'}]
```

Comment: I added some comments